# NSComboBox disappears immediately after click

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm working on an application which behaves similarly to Spotlight. However, currently I'm having a trouble with NSComboBox.

To show the application after hitting a hotkey I use `activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` and `NSWindowController(window: window).showWindow(self)`. Then when user hits `Escape` I do `window.close()` and `hide(self)`.

Everything works great, previous application gets focus. However, when I open again the window, first click on `NSComboBox` causes a very strange behavior (like on the movie below). First time it instantly disappears.

[image: bug]

I found out that it happens because of `NSApp.hide`. When I don't call it, everything works well. However, I need to call it, because I want the previous app to get the focus.

To workaround this issue I can replace NSWindow with nonactivating NSPanel. It resolves the problem. However, it's not possible in my case because I need to use it also with `presentAsModalWindow` and `presentAsSheet` where I can't control whether it's a window or panel.

I also discovered that a single click on window's background before clicking on ComboBox helps. So it seems like this window doesn't have focus, but looks like focused. I also tried all methods like `makeKeyAndOrderFront`, `becomeFirstResponder`, `NSApp.unhide` etc. etc. Nothing helps.

Under the hood NSComboBox has its own window `NSComboBoxWindow`, so my guess is that when I click it opens its window and then it receives information that the parent window took focus and dismisses itself for some reason.

I'm not sure if this is Cocoa bug or what. Is there any way to fix it?

---

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

Create new macOS project with `NSComboBox` and `NSButton`. Connect button to `IBAction`.

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        view.window?.close()
        NSApp.hide(self)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Workaround**

Finally, I managed to create a workaround. It's ugly but it works. I cover arrow part with a transparent view, intercept click and invoke two times expand via accessibility...

```swift
import Cocoa

final class ClickView: NSView {
    var onMouseDown: () -> (Bool) = { return false }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if !onMouseDown() {
            super.mouseDown(with: event)
        }
    }
}

final class FixedComboBox: NSComboBox {
    private let clickView = ClickView()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        fix()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        fix()
    }

    private func fix() {
        clickView.onMouseDown = { [weak self] in
            guard let cell = self?.cell else { return false }

            // first expand will be immediately closed because of Cocoa bug
            cell.setAccessibilityExpanded(true)

            // we need to schedule another one with a small delay to let it close the first call

            // this one almost immediately to avoid blinking
            DispatchQueue.main.async { cell.setAccessibilityExpanded(true) }

            // in case the first one didn't "catch" the right moment (sometimes it happens)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) { cell.setAccessibilityExpanded(true) }

            return true
        }

        addSubview(clickView)

        clickView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalTo(20)
            make.trailing.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `NSWindowController(window: window).showWindow(self)` create a `NSWindowController` to call `showWindow`?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. The issue is reproducible by manually hiding and activating an app.

Comment: @Willeke First question: yes, but without that problem still exists. I also added a reproducible small example and indeed it looks like a Cocoa bug :<. The question is how to work around it. I tried many things but nothing works. Maybe there is some way to simulate window click? 

Or maybe messing with `NSComboBoxWindow` could help?